# JSON Import not casting shadows in Three.JS r74

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm having issues getting a simple plane created in Blender to cast shadows when imported into Three.js

Here's my relevant code:

```
let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { 
  color: 0x00ff00, 
  morphTargets: true,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
this.paper = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.paper.castShadow = true;
this.paper.receiveShadow = true;
ThreeHub.scene.add(this.paper);

this.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this.paper);
let clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence('fallingPaper', this.paper.geometry.morphTargets, 60);
let action = new THREE.AnimationAction(clip, 0, 1, 1, THREE.LoopOnce);
this.mixer.addAction(action);

ThreeHub.scene.renderer.addRenderCallback('animation.paper', () => {
  this.mixer.update(ThreeHub.clock.getDelta());
})
```

Paper doesn't have any children. You can see my JSON file at https://gist.github.com/tomlagier/1b972b2b4d914f1ba71d

You can see the scene hosted at http://tomlagier.github.io/threejs-falling-paper/target/

Basic objects added to my scene correctly cast shadows, so I know it's an issue with this object.

Comment: where is the `object` variable loaded?

Comment: It's a little convoluted because of my framework, it's essentially getting passed in from a JSONLoader - it's a single THREE.Geometry